# How to store multiple list with three inputs

Tags: python

*what loop should I use to store the inputs of the user*

Sample output

[image: Sample output]

```
while True:

 print("1 - Add")

 guess = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
 
 a = []

 if guess == 1:
  name = str(input("Input Name: "))
  age = int(input("Enter Age: "))
  grade = float(input("Enter Grade: "))
  a = [name, age, grade]
  print(a)
```

Comment: use `a` as a 2D list. instead of "a = [name, age, grade]" do "a.append([name, age, grade])"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a outer list to store all the sublist containing each a people's info

```
values = [['Name", "Age', 'Grade']]
while True:
    print("1-Add / 2-Show")
    guess = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    if guess == 1:
        name = str(input("Input Name: "))
        age = int(input("Enter Age: "))
        grade = float(input("Enter Grade: "))
        values.append([name, age, grade])
    elif guess == 2:
        for idx, val in enumerate(values):
            print(idx, val)
```

Output

```
1-Add / 2-Show
Enter your choice: 1
Input Name: Juan
Enter Age: 25
Enter Grade: 90
1-Add / 2-Show
Enter your choice: 2
0 ['Name", "Age', 'Grade']
1 ['Juan', 25, 90.0]
```

Comment: Is there a way to edit the values in the stored list?

Comment: @RobertMangusin what king of edit ?

Comment: Like if I want to modify the stored list of " 1 ['Juan', 25, 90.0] " and i want to change their values into a new one

Comment: @RobertMangusin `values[1] = ['name', 10, 10]`

Comment: Is it just me or have there been several posts daily with this problem.  Is this problem homework for an online course?

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understood and the provided output I don't think the problem is the loop, I think you should declare the list (a) outside the while loop and use the append method instead of reassign the variable.

Something like this:

```
a = [['Name', 'Age', 'Grade']]
while True:

 print("1 - Add")

 guess = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

 if guess == 1:
  name = str(input("Input Name: "))
  age = int(input("Enter Age: "))
  grade = float(input("Enter Grade: "))
  a.append([name, age, grade])
  print(a)
```

Then you can write a function to print in the desired format (i.e. index, value)

Answer (score 0):

Let `a=[ ["name", "age", "group"] ]`

Now at the end of your code, instead of `print(a)`, do:

```
a=[ ["name", "age", "group"] ]
while True:
    .
    .
    .
    #a = [name, age, grade]
    #print(a)
    a.append([name, age, group])
    for i, item in enumerate(a):
        print(i, item)
```

Example output:

```
1-Add
Enter your choice: 1
Input Name: Juan
Enter Age: 25
Enter Grade: 90.5
0 ["name", "age", "group"]
1 [Juan, 25, 90.5]

1-Add
Enter your choice: 1
Input Name: Con
Enter Age: 20
Enter Grade: 90.2
0 ["name", "age", "group"]
1 [Juan, 25, 90.5]
2 [Con, 20, 90.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
student_list = []
student_list.append(['Name', 'Age', 'Grade'])
while True:

 print("1 - Add")

 guess = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

 if guess == 1:
  name = str(input("Input Name: "))
  age = int(input("Enter Age: "))
  grade = float(input("Enter Grade: "))
  student_list.append([name, age, grade])
  print(student_list)
```